# get_permalink() is not working after published

Tags: permalinks, actions

I created a plugin that, when updated, gets a link to a published record and sends it to the API.
So I get the URL, but sometimes wordpress gives me such a link: site.com/?p=123, and should site.com/url/

```
add_action( 'post_updated', array( $this, 'on_post_updated' ), 10, 3 );

     function on_post_updated( $post_ID, $post_after, $post_before ) {
                if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_ID ) ) {
                    return false;
                }

                $url = get_permalink( $post_ID );
                $url = $this->base_url . $url;
                wp_remote_get( $url );
            }
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Where does `on_post_updated()` run? What are your Permalink settings set to? Is `$post_id()` _published_?

Comment: i use:         add_action( 'post_updated', array( $this, 'on_post_updated' ), 10, 3 );

Comment: What is in `$this->base_url`? `get_permalink` returns a full URL, not a relative URL. Also I see you're then retrieving that URL via `wp_remote_get`, but your question says you're sending it to an API. Additionally, `example.com/?p=123` is still a URL for the post, it's just not a pretty one that's been rewritten, but it still works. Infact, internally, WP will match the URL on to a rule that transforms it from example.com/url into example/com/?p=123 etc. Some CPT's have rewrite rules turned off too. I also see the hook for `on_post_updated` is missing, can we see the `add_action` call?

Comment: I corrected the code. Forgot to write